# Sphere[] mesh/wireframe using Graphics3D

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, visualization

When using `ParametricPlot3D` to plot a sphere, we get a nice mesh / wireframe for it:

```
ParametricPlot3D[{Sin[t] Cos[p], Sin[t] Sin[p], Cos[t]}, {t, 0, \[Pi]}, {p, 0, 2 \[Pi]}]
```

[image: Sphere with mesh, using ParametricPlot3D]

Is there a way to get a similar result using the (much more efficient) `Sphere[]` primitive? Simply doing

```
Graphics3D@Sphere[]
```

produces instead

[image: Sphere without a mesh, using Graphics3D]

Comment: `Sphere[]` doesn't know about your desired meshcoordinates!

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Indeed, but internally it must have _some_ coordinates and I'm not picky about which mesh it chooses, so I'd be OK with getting a result similar to that of `Show[ParametricPlot3D[{x, y, Sqrt[1 - x^2 - y^2]}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1,
    1}], ParametricPlot3D[{x, y, -Sqrt[1 - x^2 - y^2]}, {x, -1, 
   1}, {y, -1, 1}]]`

Comment: `Sphere[]` seems to be an atomic object, I don't know how to look inside.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there a way to get a similar result using the (much more efficient) `Sphere[]` primitive?

No, the internal discretization is not accessible. But you can get something similar, with a trick, and assuming that ...

> I'm not picky about which mesh it chooses

```
DiscretizeRegion[Sphere[],
 PrecisionGoal -> 1, MaxCellMeasure -> 0.01,
 MeshCellStyle -> {{2, All} -> None, {1, All} -> Black}
]
```

[image]

Adjust the `MaxCellMeasure` to get a finer/coarser discretization. `PrecisionGoal -> 1` is there to allow very coarse discretizations.

This is not the discretization that is used to render `Sphere[]`, but it is efficient, and you said that is what you wanted.

Comment: Thanks! This comes closer to what I wanted, _i.e._ an efficient way to display wireframe meshes from 3D primitives such as Sphere[], without going through the trouble of parametrizing them myself and using ParametricPlot3D or similar. It still feels a bit roundabout, but I guess I'll mark this as a valid answer if nothing better comes up in a while...

Comment: The result is a polyhedron not a sphere anymore. To much deviation from being round at all.

Comment: @SteffenJaeschke That's true, but I was under the impression that OP specifically wanted a simple polyhedral representation. He was asking about the actual polyhedral mesh used to render `Sphere[]`. I agree that the smooth curves of `ParametricPlot3D` are nicer (and that's what I'd use), but the question seemed to ask for something different.

Answer (score 5):

You can construct 3D mesh lines using `GeometricTransformation` of two great circles:

```
ClearAll[sphereMesh]
sphereMesh[n_: 40, m_: 40, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
  Module[{tr1 = AffineTransform[{{{Sin @ #, 0, 0}, {0, Sin @ #, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}, 
      {0, 0, Cos @ #}}] & /@ Subdivide[0, 2 Pi, n],
    tr2 = RotationTransform[#, {0, 0, 1}] & /@ Subdivide[0, 2 Pi, m], 
    cp = Join[#, {First @ #}] &[CirclePoints[50]], cxy, cyz},
  cxy = Line[Append[0] /@ cp];
  cyz = Line[Insert[0, 1] /@ cp];
  Graphics3D[{Gray, MapThread[GeometricTransformation, {{cxy, cyz}, {tr1, tr2}}]}, 
  Boxed -> False, opts]]
```

***Examples:***

```
sphereMesh[]
```

[image]

```
Show[sphereMesh[50, 20],
  Graphics3D[{Opacity@.5 , LightGreen, Sphere[]}], ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

We can use `RegionMember` to view the structure of `Sphere[]`

```
RegionMember[Sphere[], {x, y, z}]
```

> `(x | y | z) ∈ Reals && x^2 + y^2 + z^2 == 1`

and then use `ContourPlot3D` to make `Mesh`

Answer (score 2):

Why not `SphericalPlot3D[1, \[Theta], \[Phi]]`[image]?

Answer (score 1):

```
Head@ParametricPlot3D[{Sin[t] Cos[p], Sin[t] Sin[p], Cos[t]}, {t, 0, \[Pi]}, {p, 0, 2 \[Pi]}]
```

(* Graphics3D *)

```
makeDashed[ g_Graphics3D ] := g /. l_Line :> {Dashed, l}

  makeDashed[ ParametricPlot3D[{Sin[t] Cos[p], Sin[t] Sin[p], Cos[t]}, {t, 0, \[Pi]}, {p, 0, 2 \[Pi]}] ]
```

[image: Dashed sphere grid]

You may give the gridlines on the sphere in `ParametricPlot3D` the Opacity You like

```
Head@Sphere[]
```

(* Sphere  *)

Nice example about the powerful `ParametricPlot3D` from [`FaceForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FaceForm.html)

```
ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[\[Phi]] Sin[\[Theta]], 
  Sin[\[Phi]] Sin[\[Theta]], Cos[\[Theta]]}, {\[Phi], 0, 
  3 Pi/2}, {\[Theta], 0, Pi}, MeshStyle -> Opacity[.2], 
 PlotStyle -> FaceForm[Blue, Orange]]
```

[image: Opened sphere]

As long as default settings are used, no `PlotPoints`, `MaxRecursion`, `WorkingPrecision`,  `PrecisionGoal`, `Precision` and `Accuracy`, `Tolerance`, both representations are of equal performance. `ParametricPlot3D` is much more versatile.

The built-in `Sphere` belongs to a set of Graphics3D primitives set included to compability reasons. This include Cube, Sphere, Parallelepiped, ... They are collected on [`SolidGeometry`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/SolidGeometry.html). Sphere is identical to [`Ball`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Ball.html). All these work with [`Lighting`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Lighting.html)

An almost white sphere with ParametricPlot can be achieved with:

```
ParametricPlot3D[{Sin[t] Cos[p], Sin[t] Sin[p], Cos[t]}, {t, 
   0, \[Pi]}, {p, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, Lighting -> {"Ambient", White}, 
  PlotStyle -> GrayLevel[.995], PlotTheme -> None]
```

[image: white sphere]

This can be made transparent:

```
ParametricPlot3D[{Sin[t] Cos[p], Sin[t] Sin[p], Cos[t]}, {t, 
  0, \[Pi]}, {p, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, Lighting -> {"Ambient", White}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Opacity[.5], GrayLevel[.995]}, PlotTheme -> None]
```

[image]

and colored arbitrarily:

```
ParametricPlot3D[{Sin[t] Cos[p], Sin[t] Sin[p], Cos[t]}, {t, 
  0, \[Pi]}, {p, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, Lighting -> {"Ambient", White}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Opacity[.5], Directive[Black, Glow[Red]]}, 
 PlotTheme -> None]
```

[image: red sphere]

This can then be shown together using `Overlay`, `Inset`, `Epilog` or `Show` together with the nice `Sphere` built-in.

Comment: Nice examples, but they don't quite answer the question

Comment: `DiscretizeRegion[]` produces a not so beautiful net. To make Yourself a new graphics primitive this should be pretty well. The storage management of Mathematica makes is be save only ones and is it close to the atomic `Sphere[]`.  The intent is giving the same power as Sphere to the user be collecting appropriate methods and options. The mesh can not be made the same like this with `DiscretizeRegion[]`!